# Find the sum of the maximum and minimum values of $|\arcsin x|+|\arccos x| $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, maxima-minima

> If maximum and minimum value of $|\arcsin x|+|\arccos x| $ is represented by $M$  and $m$, respectively, then find $M+m$.

Since $ -\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \arcsin x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, we have$$0 \leq |\arcsin x| \leq \frac{\pi}{2} .$$

Also, $ \pi \leq \arccos x \leq 0$, so$$ \frac{\pi}{2} \leq |\arccos x| \leq 0 .$$

Can we proceed in this way... please guide... the correct method thanks..

Comment: Break it into $-1 < x < 0$ and $0 < x < 1$. Now you can get rid of the absolute values and derive it to find the extreme values.

Comment: Note that, when $ -1\leq x \leq 1 \implies 0\leq \arccos x \leq \pi .$

Comment: Note that, $m=0$ and $M=\frac{3\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we proceed in this way...

Yes. For the $sin^{-1}(x)$, use the chain rule to take the derivative of $|sin^{-1}(x)|$:

$$\frac{d}{dx}|sin^{-1}(x)|=\frac{|sin^{-1}(x)|}{sin^{-1}(x)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Find the critical points b finding when the derivative equals 0, and you'll find that it equals 0 when x = 0. Since the only other two critical points are the boundaries, which are both $\pi/2$, 0 must be the minimum, and $\pi/2$ must be the maximum.

The same can be done for $cos^{-1}(x)$, but you'll find that $cos^{-1}(x)$ has no critical points in its domain. This means that the minimum and maximum are simply the endpoints of its co-domain (also known as range).